# Calculate Time Complexity of function

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I am thinking about how to correctly calculate time complexity of this function:

```
def foo(lst):
    jump = 1
    total = 0
    while jump < len(lst):
        for i in range(0, len(lst), jump):
            total += i
        jump = jump * 2
    return total
```

I assume that it's O(n) where n is length of list.
Our while loop is O(n) and for loop is also O(n), that means that we got 2*O(n) which equals O(n).
Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation have mistakes, for nested loop we multiply the complexity of outer loop with the complexity of inner loop to get the full complexity.

If `n` is the length of list then the while loop runs `log(n)` time as every time we are using `jump = jump * 2`

Inner loop is like, `n/1` times when `jump = 1`, and `n/2` times when jump is 2, so the complexity of inner loop is like : (n/1) + (n/2) + (n/4) + (n/8) .... till logn times

Hence total time complexity = n(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 +… till logn). The coefficient of `n` here is negligible, so the complexity is `O(n)`